# Question Concerning Magnitude And Direction Of The Accleration For Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, physics

To find the magnitude and direction of the acclleration for the uniform circular motion,we consider the below figure [image]

Where in particle $p$ moves at constant speed $v$ around a circle of radius $r$.At the instant shown,$p$ has coordinates $x_{p}$ and $y_{p}$.
since velocity $\vec{v}$ of a moving particle is always tangent to the particle's path at the particle's position.In the above figure that means $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to a radius $r$ drawn to the particle's position.

> How does the angle $\theta$ that $\vec{v}$ makes with a verticle at $p$ equals the angle $\theta$ that radius $r$ makes with the $x$-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear pair axiom does the job here.

Note that, the line marked $y_p$ is a straight line.

**Linear Pair Axioms:**

1. If a ray stands on line, then the sum of two adjacent angles so formed is $180^\circ$.
2. If the sum of two adjacent angles is $180^\circ$, then the non-common arms of the angles form a line.

Also, note that sum of the interior angles in a triangle is $180 ^\circ$.

Comment: Oh ya..High school geometry!